# Intersection of the two hypersurfaces $ax^2-y^2-b$ and $a'x^2-z^2-b'$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm interested in understanding the intersection of the hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by
$ax^2-y^2-b$ and $a'x^2-z^2-b'$, where $a,a',b,b'$ are nonzero constants.

Is this smooth? Irreducible? What is the genus of its compactification? I'd like to understand how to see this without resorting to a computer algebra package.

Comment: E.g. $-x^2/2-y^2=-1, -x^2/2-z^2=-2$ are two elliptical cylinders that intersect in a curve, in two ovals over ${\Bbb R}.$ But it is smooth irreducible and of genus $1$ over ${\Bbb C}$. But for it to be an elliptic curve you'd need a rational point, and I don't think it has such over ${\Bbb Q}.$ BTW It's possible to get a twisted cubic and a line (reducible) from an intersection of two quadrics (the standard example is $\langle x-yz,y^2-xz\rangle$), and you'd need a third quadric containing the twisted cubic and a different line skew to the one you had to get it alone (irreducible).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt need a computer algebra package here: break things down into cases here and do a few examples over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Over $\mathbb{R}$, when $b, b' = 0$ youre looking at two lines $y = \sqrt{a}x$ and $y = -\sqrt{a}x$ which intersect at the origin, together with the lines $z = \sqrt{a'}x$ and $z = -\sqrt{a'}x$ — so you get four lines intersecting at the origin, giving you a point counted with multiplicity 4. It's obviously irreducible.

In general over an algebraically closed field, you would just use Bezouts theorem to say that this will be four points counted with multiplicity, so it doesnt really make sense to talk about genus.

Comment: No, the general case would be (regarded in ${\Bbb P}^3$ over an algebraically closed field like ${\Bbb C}$; Bezout would apply to the intersection of three quadrics giving $2^3=8$ points.) the intersection of two rank 3 quadrics (by letting b,b' be 0 you're restricting to rank 2) which generally is an irreducible curve, but can (maybe not for the given quadrics) be reducible (a twisted cubic curve and a line $\langle yw-z^2,y^2-xz\rangle$).